# Job and device/shadow running at same time on the device

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot

As we know the device can only run one single connection by same client id, based on that. A physical device opens a connection with the `device` implementation to subscribe to the AWS IoT Shadow. I was wondering how it that will work based on the `jobs` implementation seems to create another new MQTT client

Answer (score 0):

You use the same connection you already have for your device to use jobs. Jobs are used through publish and subscribe to specific topics. You can read more about jobs MQTT API here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jobs-api.html#mqtt-describejobexecution